# Función suma en Haskell

Tags: lista, haskell

El programa tiene que leer un número que se considera lista, pero solo da bien el resultado con dos cifras, con más de dos cifras el resultado es incorrecto ¿Cómo se puede corregir este código?

```
sumDigitos :: [Int] -> Int
sumDigitos [] = 0
sumDigitos [x] = x `div` 10 + x `mod` 10
sumDigitos (x:xs) = sumDigitos [x] + sumDigitos xs
```

Ejemplo de entrada

[1234]

Salida:

10

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo de lista y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta con ejemplo de entrada y salida

Comment: Supongo que sabes que `[1234] ` es una lista de un solo elemento, el número `1234`¿lo que necesitas es sumar sus dígitos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La suma de los dígitos de un número `n` se define recursivamente como el último dígito del número (el resto de `n` módulo `10`) más la suma del resto de dígitos (la llamada recursiva de `n` dividido entre `10`):

```
sumDigitos' :: Int -> Int
sumDigitos' 0 = 0
sumDigitos' n = n `mod` 10 + sumDigitos' (n `div` 10)
```

Por ejemplo:

```
ghci> sumDigitos' 1234
10
```

Ahora, para sumar los dígitos de una lista de números simplemente hay que sumar la suma de los dígitos de cada número:

```
sumDigitos :: [Int] -> Int
sumDigitos [] = 0
sumDigitos (x:xs) = sumDigitos' x + sumDigitos xs
```

Por ejemplo:

```
ghci> sumDigitos [123,456,789]
45
```

También podrías definir `sumDigitos` directamente en [estilo libre de puntos](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) mediante las funciones `map` y `sum`:

```
sumDigitos :: [Int] -> Int
sumDigitos = sum . (map sumDigitos')
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa el apóstrofe después de, por ejemplo, sumDigits'?

Comment: Forma parte del nombre de la función. `sumDigitos`, `sumDigitos'`, `sumDigitos''`, etcétera son identificadores válidos para funciones, pero no tienen porqué tener nada que ver, son funciones distintas.

Comment: Ahh, para diferenciarlas

Answer (score 0):

Voy a proponer una solución más curiosa. Para obtener los dígitos de un número podemos convertirlo primero a una cadena de caracteres (lista de *chars*) y luego ir sumando cada digito:

```
sumDigitos' :: Int -> Int
sumDigitos' n = sum [read [c] | c <- show n]
```

Podemos emplear una función de `Data.Char` para que sea más simple:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

sumDigitos' :: Int -> Int
sumDigitos' n = sum (map digitToInt (show n))
```

que podemos reescribir como *pointfree*:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

sumDigitos' :: Int -> Int
sumDigitos' = sum . map digitToInt . show
```

Podemos aplicar esta función a cada número de la lista, o también podemos concatenar los dígitos de todos los números en una única lista de *chars*:

```
digitos :: [Int] -> [Char]
digitos xs = concatMap show xs
```

Juntando todo:

```
sumDigitos :: [Int] -> Int
sumDigitos xs = sum . map digitToInt $ concatMap show xs
```

que también puede ser reescrito en *pointfree* quedando finalmente como:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

sumDigitos :: [Int] -> Int
sumDigitos = sum . map digitToInt . concatMap show
```

Es una composición de tres funciones:

- `concatMap show` --> convierte la lista de números en una lista de caracteres, un dígito por caracter
- `map digitToInt` --> convierte cada caracter en un número entero
- `sum`--> suma todo